# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow'

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net-2010

I have a 4 tier architecture using asp.net 4.0 
1- Web application
2- Business object
3- Business Logic
4- Data Logic

i have used factory method to create dynamic forms. on a radio button list selected index changed event ,  i want to hide/show a table row which is also created dynamically. table row is available in session. i am using the following code

```
Private Sub parameter_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try
            Dim rdbtn As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(sender, RadioButtonList)
            Dim selectedText As String = rdbtn.SelectedItem.Text
            Dim worksRequiredRowId = SessionManager.getWorksRequiredRowId()
            Dim worksRequiredRow As TableRow = CType(sender.FindControl(worksRequiredRowId), TableRow)


            If selectedText.ToUpper <> ApplicationConstants.conditionSatisfactory.ToUpper Then

                worksRequiredRow.Style.Add("display", "table-row")
            Else

                worksRequiredRow.Style.Add("display", "none")
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

And i get the following error.

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList' to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow'.

Please help me to find out the solution.
Best ragards.

Comment: What's the markup code matching the Ids? Specifically worksRequiredRowId?

Comment: worksrequiredRowId is "tr_WorksRequired_186".

Comment: <tr id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Attributes_itemDetailControl_detailsTabID_tr_WorksRequired_186" style="height:30px;"><td id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Attributes_itemDetailControl_detailsTabID_td1_186" align="right"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Attributes_itemDetailControl_detailsTabID_lblTextBox186">Works Required: </span></td><td id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Attributes_itemDetailControl_detailsTabID_td2_186"></td> </tr>

Answer (score 1):

You can actually hide that particular item from radio button list instead of converting it into table row. Something like this.

```
If rdbtn.SelectedItem.Text <> selectedText.ToUpper <> ApplicationConstants.conditionSatisfactory.ToUpper Then 

rdbtn.Items(itemIndex).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none")
End If
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it hide the first item of radiobuttonlist. i want to hide a different rowId.

Comment: Yes, that was just an example you can actually use the item index.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is confusing the generated HTML markup with the raw ASP.NET markup. `RadioButtonList` does create an HTML  for each item, but you can't access that rows at the server-side (to make them visible or hidden).

You should either use the server-side method mentioned in Bridewin D.P.'s answer or transfer the code to client-side and use Javascript to manipulate the rows.

Server-side would look something like this:

```
Private Sub parameter_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim rdbtn As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(sender, RadioButtonList)
        Dim selectedText As String = rdbtn.SelectedItem.Text
        Dim worksRequiredRowId = SessionManager.getWorksRequiredRowId()

        Dim style as String

        If selectedText.ToUpper <> ApplicationConstants.conditionSatisfactory.ToUpper Then
            style= "table-row"
        Else
            style= "none"
        End If

        rdbtn.Items(worksRequiredRowId).Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", style)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: radiobuttonlist contain the different rowId, and i want to hide a different rowid.

Comment: So explain what you want clearly. From your original code, I get that you want a TableRow inside the `RadioButtonList`, but there is no such thing on the server side :)